# Multiple Include Optimization

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, include-guards

I'm trying to understand how [multiple-include optimization](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Guard-Macros.html#Guard-Macros) works with gcc.
Lately, I've been reading a lot code that has include guards for standard header files like so

```
#ifndef _STDIO_H_
#include <stdio.h>
#endif
```

and I'm trying to figure out if this construct has any benefits.

Here's an example I wrote to understand this a little better.

header1.h

```
#ifndef _HDR_H_
#define _HDR_H_

#define A    (32)

#endif
```

header2.h

```
#ifndef _HDR_H_
#define _HDR_H_

#define A    (64)

#endif
```

hdr.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"

int main()
{
     printf("%d\n", A);
     return 0;
}
```

Note that both `header1.h` and `header2.h` use the same include guard. As expected this program outputs the value of `A` defined in header1.h; header2.h is skipped since it uses the same include guard.

Here's what I'm trying to understand

- At what point when parsing header2.h does the preprocessor skip this file? My understanding is that it skips this file immediately after the `#if` directive on line 1, i.e. it does not have to wait for the matching `#endif`. Is this correct?
- What can I add to the example above to demonstrate how this works?

EDIT: Thanks everyone for the answers. This is starting to make more sense now. A follow up question. The page linked to on the first line of this post has the following text

> The preprocessor notices such header files, so that if the header file
>   appears in a subsequent #include directive and FOO is defined, then it
>   is ignored and it doesn't preprocess or even re-open the file a second
>   time. This is referred to as the multiple include optimization.

If I understand this correctly, this means that any header file is read only once even it is included multiple times for a given compile process. And so, additional include guards in application code or header file provide no benefit.

Comment: Normally I make my include guards to be the uppercase name of the file substituting . with _ so that that one include guard does not disable a second in a different file. However since most compilers support #pragma once I use that above the include guard these days.

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_HDR_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation (the compiler and its headers). Don't use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**At what point when parsing header2.h does the preprocessor skip this file?**

The file is not skipped.

**My understanding is that it skips this file immediately after the #if directive on line 1, i.e. it does not have to wait for the matching #endif. Is this correct?**

Yes and No. Some compilers identify the sentry macro when it parses the first header file and if it finds it in a second file, it will immediately stop parsing. Other compilers will parse the header again (looking for the matching `#endif`).

**What can I add to the example above to demonstrate how this works?**

Add a print message inside and outside the sentry macro

```
#ifdef   _HEADER_INCLUDED
#define  _HEADER_INCLUDED
...
#pragma message ("inside sentry in " __FILE__ "\n")
#endif //#ifdef   _HEADER_INCLUDED

#pragma message ("outside sentry in " __FILE__ "\n")
```

**Relevant material:**

- You can use `#pragma once` instead of the sentry macro. Faster compilation since very little of the file is parsed. No worries about macro name collisions.
- You can wrap the includes if checks to sentry macro so the header file isn't loaded again. This is usually used in library headers that include multiple headers many times. Can significantly speed up compilation at the expense of ugly code:

  `#ifndef __LIST_H_`

  `#include "list.h"`

  `#endif`

Comment: According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Guard-Macros.html , adding stuff after `#endif` would disable the optimization altogether, thus failing the purpose of observing how the optimization works.

Answer (score 4):

> At what point when parsing header2.h does the preprocessor skip this file?

As @Sean says, `header2.h` will never be skipped, but the content between the `ifndef ... endif` will be ignored in this case.

---

> What can I add to the example above to demonstrate how this works?

Add something (for example, a `#define B 123`) **after** the `#endif` in `header2.h`. Now try to access it in the `main`. It will be accessible.

Now, try to add it **before** the `#endif`. You'll see, that it's not accessible in the `main.

Comment: Thanks! I did confirm that it works as you explained.

Comment: According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Guard-Macros.html , adding stuff after `#endif` would disable the optimization altogether, thus failing the purpose of observing how the optimization works.

Answer (score 2):

The pre-processor will never skip header2.h. It will always include it, and when expanding it will ignore the stuff in the `#ifndef` block.

In your example `A` will be 32, as the `#define` in herader2.h will never be reached. If it was reached you'd get some sort of "macro redefinition error" as you'd have multiple `#define`s for "A". To fix this you#d need to `#undef` A.

Most compilers support the `#pragma once` directive these days to save you having to write include guards in header files.

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor starts blocking all input that follows a false `#if[[n]def]` to go to through subsequent compiler steps.

The preprocessor does however continues reading the input, to keep track of nesting depth of all those conditional compilation `#`-directives.

When it finds the matching `#endif`, of where it started blocking input, it simply stops blocking.

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand this correctly, this means that any header file is read only once even it is included multiple times for a given compile process. And so, additional include guards in application code or header file provide no benefit.

No gcc compiler only does this optimization for files that it knows to be safe following the rules:

1. There must be no tokens outside the controlling #if-#endif pair, but whitespace and comments are permitted.
2. There must be no directives outside the controlling directive pair, but the null directive (a line containing nothing other than a single ‘#’ and possibly whitespace) is permitted.
3. The opening directive must be of the form

   ```
     #ifndef FOO
   ```

   or

   ```
     #if !defined FOO     [equivalently, #if !defined(FOO)]
   ```